# Parsing arithmetic expression with variable using menhir meet priority problem

Tags: parsing, ocaml, menhir

parser.mly

```
%{
  let env=Hashtbl.create 10
%}
%token <int> INT
%token SUB
%token EOL
%token EQUAL
%token NAME
%left SUB 
%right EQUAL

%start main             /* the entry point */
%type<int> main
%%
 main:
  expr EOL                { $1 }
;

expr:
   INT                     { $1} 
  | expr SUB expr           { $1 - $3}
  | var EQUAL expr {Hashtbl.add env $1 $3;0}
  | var {Hashtbl.find env $1}
;

var:NAME {$1}
```

Gives the following result when executed

```
a=1
0
b=2
0
a-b-5
-6
a=1-3
-3
a
1
```

which means that `a=1`, `b=2`, `a-b-5` returns the right answer, but `a=1-3` doesn't.

If I change the priority:

```
%left EQUAL
%right SUB
```

then I have

```
a=1-3
0
a
-2
a=1
0
b=2
0
a-b-5
4
```

so it seems I haven't understood the priority in Menhir. How do I fix it? Thanks!

and the line

```
| var EQUAL expr {Hashtbl.add env $1 $3;0}
```

I really need is

```
Hashtbl.add env $1 $3
```

but it seems that I have to define the type of main,and I can't define

```
%type<unit> main
```

so I have to write the ugly '0',how to fix it?

other files:
lexer.mll:

```
{
open Parser
exception Eof
}
rule token = parse
  [' ' '\t']     { token lexbuf }     (* skip blanks *)
| ['\n' ]        { EOL }
 | ['0'-'9']+ as lxm { INT(int_of_string lxm) } 
| '-'            { SUB }
|['a'-'z']+ {NAME}
|'=' {EQUAL}
| eof            { raise Eof }
```

calc.ml

```
open Syntax

let _ =
  try
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
    while true do
      let result = Parser.main Lexer.token lexbuf in
      print_int result;
      print_newline ();
      flush stdout
    done
  with Lexer.Eof -> exit 0
```

makefile:

```
calc:lexer.cmo parser.cmo syntax.cmo calc.cmo 
    ocamlc -o calc lexer.cmo parser.cmo syntax.cmo calc.cmo

lexer.cmo:lexer.mll
    ocamllex lexer.mll
    
parser.cmo:parser.mly
    menhir parser.mly

syntax.cmo:syntax.ml
    ocamlc -c syntax.ml

calc.cmo:calc.ml
    ocamlc -c lexer.ml
    ocamlc -c parser.mli
    ocamlc -c parser.ml
    ocamlc -c calc.ml
```

Comment: You should only ask 1 question per post. The priority thing is a question on its own, which is distinct from the question about the type of `main` and having to add a `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing priority and associativity of operators. Menhir declaration of tokens sets both of these: with `%left SUB`, you are declaring that something of the form `a-b-c` should be parsed as `(a-b)-c` rather than `a-(b-c)`. Similarly, with `%right EQUAL`, you are saying that `a=b=c` should be parsed as `a=(b=c)`, which is probably right in the sense that this the usual associativity of these operators in popular programming languages (ie. C).

However, the *order* of these declaration also matters: it indicates whether `a=b-c` should be parsed as `a=(b-c)` or `(a=b)-c`. By declaring `SUB` before `EQUAL`, `EQUAL` will have greater priority, so it's the latter parsing that will happen (which is not what you want). Likely, what you want is therefore the following:

```
%right EQUAL
%left SUB
```

Also, note that it doesn't make a lot of sense (from my point of view) to see `a=b` as an expression if it always returns `0`. Maybe you meant to return the value of `b` instead, so that you can chain assignments?